# UIScrollview Content Pushed To Left Side

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I followed this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjTS9fyWqdg and finally managed to at least get my scroll view to scroll however now when i open the app on the simulator the content is showing and i can scroll but all views inside of the scrollviews "content view" seem to be pushed towards the left. I can't seem to figure out why its doing this I've tried centering just about everything horizontally in their containers with no luck. Is this a common issue maybe even just another bug in auto layout?

Comment: please see this link https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/ for detailed information on autolayout with scrollviews

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by settings the content view children to center horizontally. Before i was setting it to center in the content view but that wasn't working